# Trouble with the navigation bar when in mobile form in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

**Problem:** When i previewed my website in mobile, i saw that there is no button for showing/hiding the navigation bar links and the links are now shown and can't be hidden. When i tested the navbars on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top, they work perfectly. 
I tried reloading bootstrap but nothing happens.

Is there something wrong with the code or did i miss something?

Here is the fiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/td9p60qr/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Jakob Aindreas Rivera</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
      body { padding-top: 70px; }
    </style>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Jakob Aindreas Rivera</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="projects/projects.html">Projects Home</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="projects/glass.html">Glass</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects/clockjs.html">ClockJS</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects/pixelblocksmod.html">PixelBlocks Mod</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome to my webzone!</h1>
        <p>Hello and my name is Jakob Aindreas Rivera, and this is my webzone. Feel free to browse the site!</p>
        <p>Thank you for stopping by! ;)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h2>News</h2>
      </div>
      <article>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>PixelBlocks intial release soon!</h3>
                <p>THe new MC mod PixelBlocks will now have it's intial release date soon!</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it but the answer above helped my problem too.

What i did is to rearrange my JavaScript files, i moved jQuery from the line after the bootstrap JS file to the line before the Bootstrap JS file.

Example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are using this feature incorrectly. Below you could find a part with `navbar` only.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jakob Aindreas Rivera</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Navbar Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also here is the link to js-fiddle: [Navbar jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk8bma85/).

Comment: thank you it helped the problem, but the button is not working till i re-arrange the JS files. Thank you for helping solving it! ;)